# Why get_posts() return empty data?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get posts of some type matching a meta query, but whatever I try, I get empty results.
I have

```
        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => '_wpm_gtin_code',
                'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => '_product_code',
                'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
            )
        );
        $args = array(
            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
            //'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        error_log(print_r($args, true));
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        error_log(print_r($posts, true));
```

and I see in log file

```
[02-Mar-2020 06:51:12 UTC] Array
(
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _wpm_gtin_code
                    [compare] => EXISTS
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _product_code
                    [compare] => EXISTS
                )

        )

    [post_type] => product
    [post_status] => publish
)

[02-Mar-2020 06:51:12 UTC] Array
(
)
```

When I select the data manually with this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
(wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wpm_gtin_code' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_product_code')
```

I get correct result of two rows.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you used compare "EXISTS" and not using '=' or 'like' ?

Comment: Because I just want to know that the product has such meta record no matter what's its value. I tried `'compare' => '!=', 'value' = ''`, it doesn't work too.

Comment: Added ''value'' in your meta query

Comment: @DipakDholakiya see my comment bellow answer. Adding value won't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => '_wpm_gtin_code',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        'value' => '' // This is ignored, but is necessary...
    ),
    array(
        'key' => '_product_code',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        'value' => '' // This is ignored, but is necessary...
    )
);

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    //'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```

try adding `'value' => ''` in array ...

Comment: Hello, it won't help, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Accepted_Arguments ("You don't have to specify a value when using the 'EXISTS' or 'NOT EXISTS' comparisons in WordPress 3.9 and up."). I have WordPress 5.3. But to be sure I added `value => ''`, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I dived into WP code to find out that the query contained `tax_query` even I didn't pass any to my `get_post()` call. So I searched where the query got altered and found that the whole problem was in `WooCommerceCategoryExcluder` plugin which hooked to `pre_get_posts` and added taxonomy query to my `get_posts()` args.

Maybe this investigation helps someone else trying to solve similar problem.